# preg_replace to capitalize a letter after a quote

Tags: php, regex

I have names like this:

```
$str = 'JAMES "JIMMY" SMITH'
```

I run `strtolower`, then `ucwords`, which returns this:

```
$proper_str = 'James "jimmy" Smith'
```

I'd like to capitalize the second letter of words in which the first letter is a double quote.  Here's the regexp.  It appears strtoupper is not working - the regexp simply returns the unchanged original expression.

```
$proper_str = preg_replace('/"([a-z])/',strtoupper('$1'),$proper_str);
```

Any clues?  Thanks!!

Comment: What output are you expecting ?

Comment: I think:  James "Jimmy" Smith.  Presently ucwords() is not capitalizing the first letter of Jimmy as it does not recognize double quotes as a word boundary character.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use the [*e* modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) to have the substitution be evaluated:

```
preg_replace('/"[a-z]/e', 'strtoupper("$0")', $proper_str)
```

Where `$0` contains the match of the whole pattern, so `"` and the lowercase letter. But that doesn’t matter since the `"` doesn’t change when send through `strtoupper`.

Comment: I think I made it more difficult than it needs to be as `strtoupper('"')==='"'`. ;-)

Comment: Apparently the `e` option is a severe security vulnerability and they recommend using `preg_replace_callback()` instead. FYI.

Comment: +1 Buttle comment, +1 cletus and mcfedr's answer, as it does not create a security vulnerability

Comment: This feature has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.5.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged.

Comment: /e will no longer work in PHP 7 http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php#refsect1-function.preg-replace-changelog

Comment: I know it's 8 years later, but you should update this answer or link to https://stackoverflow.com/a/2638319/3917091 since `/e` is no longer supported.

Comment: PHP Warning: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is no longer supported, use preg_replace_callback instead in

Answer (score 38):

Probably the best way to do this is using [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php):

```
$str = 'JAMES "JIMMY" SMITH';
echo preg_replace_callback('!\b[a-z]!', 'upper', strtolower($str));

function upper($matches) {
  return strtoupper($matches[0]);
}
```

You can use the `e` (eval) flag on `preg_replace()` but I generally advise against it. Particularly when dealing with external input, it's potentially extremely dangerous.

Comment: I got an error that 'upper' is not a valid callback.  When I replaced 'upper' with 'strtoupper', I got 'ARRAY' instead of capital letter 'J'

Comment: @Summer then you didn't define the `upper()` function as per my code snippet.

Comment: As mentioned by @mcfedr, starting from PHP 5.3 you can use an [anonymous function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php): `preg_replace_callback(..., function($matches) { ...`

Comment: Is definitely the best way now, `/e` is no longer supported.

Answer (score 24):

Use `preg_replace_callback` - But you dont need to add an extra named function, rather use an anonymous function.

```
$str = 'JAMES "JIMMY" SMITH';
echo preg_replace_callback('/\b[a-z]/', function ($matches) {
     return strtoupper($matches[0]);
}, strtolower($str));
```

Use of `/e` is be deprecated as of PHP 5.5 and doesn't work in PHP 7

Answer (score 4):

A complete solution doesn't get simpler / easier to read than this...

Code: https://3v4l.org/rrXP7

```
$str = 'JAMES "JIMMY" SMITH';
echo ucwords(strtolower($str), ' "');
```

Output:

```
James "Jimmy" Smith
```

It is merely a matter of declaring double quotes and spaces as delimiters in the `ucwords()` call.

---

Nope.  My earlier self was not correct.  It doesn't get simpler than this multibyte-safe title-casing technique!

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/TjOpH))

```
echo mb_convert_case($str, MB_CASE_TITLE);
```

Output:

```
James "Jimmy" Smith
```

Answer (score 0):

I do this without regex, as part of my custom `ucwords()` function. Assuming no more than two quotes appear in the string:

```
$parts = explode('"', $string, 3); 
if(isset($parts[2])) $string = $parts[0].'"'.ucfirst($parts[1]).'"'.ucfirst($parts[2]);            
else if(isset($parts[1])) $string = $parts[0].'"'.ucfirst($parts[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do this :

```
$proper_str = 
    preg_replace_callback(
        '/"([a-z])/',
        function($m){return strtoupper($m[1]);},
        $proper_str
);
```

You should'nt use "eval()" for security reasons.

Anyway, the patern modifier "e" is deprecated.
See : [PHP Documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php#reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.eval).

Answer (score 0):

```
echo ucwords(mb_strtolower('JAMES "JIMMY" SMITH', 'UTF-8'), ' "'); // James "Jimmy" Smith
```

[`ucwords()`](http://php.net/manual/function.ucwords.php) has a second delimiter parameter, the optional delimiters contains the word separator characters. Use space ' ' and `"` as delimiter there and "Jimmy" will be correctly recognized.