# How can i make uppercase letter in php regex after underscore

Tags: php, regex

I am replacing the `first_name_user` with 'firstNameUser' in php.

I am trying this

`$key1 = preg_replace('/_([a-z]?)/', '\U\1', $key);`

and its not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$key1 = preg_replace('/_([a-z]?)/e', 'strtoupper("$1")', $key);
```

But this uses the [`e` modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) which has [some <s>issues</s> security implications](https://www.google.com/#q=preg_replace+e+modifier+vulnerability) and is [deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) anyways.

> [**Caution**](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)
>
> [Use of this modifier is discouraged, as it can easily introduce security vulnerabilites](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)

Better use:

```
$key1 = preg_replace_callback('/_([a-z]?)/', function($match) {
            return strtoupper($match[1]);
        }, $key);
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638288/preg-replace-to-capitalize-a-letter-after-a-quote) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18202542/uppercase-each-first-letter-of-words-with-preg-replace) for more examples / code and information.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate to @roblll answer, if you don't want to use regex, you could use:

```
$str = "some_underscored_text";
$new_str = lcfirst(str_replace(' ', '', ucwords(str_replace('_', ' ', $str))));

echo $new_str;     // Outputs: someUnderscoredText
```

Comment: That would cause problems with a string like `some_value foo_bar baz_foo` which *should* become `someValue fooBar bazFoo` but *would* become `someValueFooBarBazFoo`. Replacing chars with "placeholders" and then back again almost invariably always causes more problems than it solves. If you really want to avoid using a regex, use a tokenizer.

Comment: @RobIII I see what you mean, I thought it would have been one_underscored_string_per_call rather than a sentence which includes underscored phrases :)

Comment: Assumptions are the mother of all f*ckups ;-) But I do agree; when that would've been (or is) the case it should work fine and OP is not clear about this in his/her question. It's just that this method (using "placeholders") *in general* is, usually, not a good idea.